# ServerStack displaying a snapshot of my request/response instead of the appropriate view page

Tags: servicestack

Here's the structure of my solution (in a grossly simplified format for brevity):

```
Project.API
    TestRequest.cs
    TestResponse.cs
    ITestService.cs

Project.Web
    /App_Start
        AppHost.cs
    /Services
        TestService.cs
    /Views
        Test.cshtml
    _Layout.cshtml
    Web.config
```

Where:

```
public interface ITestService
{
    TestResponse Get(TestRequest request);
}
```

and

```
public class TestService : Service, ITestService
{
    public TestResponse Get(TestRequest request)
    {
        return new TestResponse() 
        { 
            // ... set response properties ...
        };
    }
}
```

If I decorate `TestService` with `[DefaultView("Test")]` then everything works correctly, i.e. navigating to the URL `localhost/test` produces expected output rendered by `Test.cshtml`.

However, if I remove the `[DefaultView("Test")]` attribute from the class or move it down to the `Get()` method I get a snapshot of my request/response instead of the view's output.

It seems that ServiceStack has trouble looking up the view based on the response DTO when the DTO is defined in a different project. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, I misunderstood the instructions in http://razor.servicestack.net/#unified-stack

> ... ServiceStack's view selection is based on the name of the Response
>   or Request model (DTO) returned. E.g. If your Service returns a
>   RockstarsResponse then we first look for a view of the same name as
>   the Request DTO called Rockstars.cshtml followed by the Response DTO
>   name RockstarsResponse.cshtml (in all registered view engine
>   extensions).

I thought the request DTO in the Razor Rockstars example was called `RockstarsRequest` but it's just `Rockstars`, so as soon as renamed my request DTO from `TestRequest` to just plain `Test` things immediately started working.

Answer (score 0):

No. I dont't think servicestack find view based on DTO. At least you need to give default view. Here is the project that can give better understanding of it.

[Razor Rockstars](https://github.com/ServiceStack/RazorRockstars)

Basically servicestack is API framework not a web development framework. Viewengine is just a addon that can be useful if we need a view instead of metadata to explain API or to do something.

Even view support is useful if you wanted to create single page application.

Please let me know if any further details needed.